# Wrong return value in Runge Kutta C#

Tags: c#

Could someone please tell me, why It always returns the same "y" value? I've searched a lot on the Internet and I still don't know why it is not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inżynierkuuuu
{
class Lecimy
{
    double t, y, krok, cel;

    public Lecimy(double t, double y, double krok, double cel)
    {
        this.t = t;
        this.y = y;
        this.krok = krok;
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    public delegate double funkcja(double t, double y);

    public double RK(double t, double y, double krok, funkcja yp)
    {
        double k1 = krok * yp(t, y);
        double k2 = krok * yp(t + krok * 0.5, y + k1 * 0.5);
        double k3 = krok * yp(t + krok * 0.5, y + k2 * 0.5);
        double k4 = krok * yp(t + krok, y + k3);

        double reszta = 1 / 6 * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

        this.y = y + reszta;

        return y;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while(t < cel)
        {
            y = RK(t, y, krok, FN1);
            t = t + krok;
            Console.WriteLine("t: {0}, y: {1}", t, y);
        }
    }

    public double FN1(double t, double y)
    {
        return y;
    }

}
}
```

Second class:
The "y" value here is 1, when I change It e.g.to 5, it will always return 5 in the Output window.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Lecimy e = new Lecimy(0.0, 1.0, 0.0001, 1.0); 
        e.Run();
        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what this is meant to be doing, which makes it very hard to help you. Have you stepped through the code to work out which precise calculation is behaving differently from what you expect?

Comment: I want to implement the RK method for differential equations e.g. dy/dt=t^2 when placed in the FN1 method. No matter what equation is there, the output value is always the same as pointed out in the second class.

Comment: That doesn't answer the stepping through aspect. You should understand what you expect each line of your code to do - so you should be able to tell when that's not happening.

Comment: Yes @JonSkeet Skeet Watch list and step-by-step going through were very helpfull. I've noticed that the "y" value is not changing in the RK method.

Comment: Right, so you should identify which line you *expect* to make it change, then you can narrow the problem down. Just "the result is wrong" shows a lack of diagnostic process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious issues with your code even though I don't understand what you are trying to do.

1. `1/6` will always be zero, you should be doing `1.0/6`. The reason being that in the former, the `/(int, int)` overload is chosen.
2. You are conflating the argument `y` with the class field `y`.
   Do *not* name a local variable / argument / field with the same name, its confusing and very
   error prone; in method `RK`, are you sure you shouldn't be returning
   `this.y`? Are you sure `this.y = y + reszta` is correct and it
   shouldn't be `this.y += reszta`. See how confusing this is?

Comment: Thank you! It actually helped me. It is finally working.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you want to do, but I'm sure the following line is not what yo want:

```
double reszta = 1 / 6 * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);
```

`reszta` will always be zero. `1 / 6` is `0`, as both 1 and 6 are integers. Use `1.0 / 6` or something similar.